# Differential Equations: Solve $(x^2-1){dy\over dx} + 2xy = x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I managed to get to

$$y = {x^2+2C\over 2x^2-2}$$

Not sure if this is right. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your method!

Comment: Did you try to check if the solution satisfies the equation ?

Comment: Your solution is correct. However since $C$ is arbitrary, you don't need to multiply it by 2.

Comment: You can see that, with the product rule, $((x^2-1)\cdot y)' = (x^2-1)y' + 2x\cdot y$, so all you have is $\frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)\cdot y) = x$. Integrate both sides with respect to $x$, you get $(x^2-1)\cdot y = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$, solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. A nice way to get there is to notice that $2x=(x^2-1)^{'}$ and thus rewrite the equation

$${d\over dx}\left((x^2-1)y\right)=x$$

And therefore

$$(x^2-1)y={x^2+C\over 2}$$

And we get

$$y={x^2+C\over 2(x^2-1)}$$